# Seekbar present or not in titanium

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, seekbar

Hi I am searching for the seek bar in titanium just like android,But i have not come across such thing in documentation.Actually i want to change the value manually.I have seen progress bar but not seekbar.Can any body tell does titanium has implemented seekbar and if not what could be alternative way .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want Ti.UI.Slider.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Slider